# How to extract all unique pairs of a list in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

I am pretty new to Haskell and I have a question. How can I write a function to return all the unique possible pairs of a list? Like: 
[1,2,3,4] -> [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)]

Comment: how should your function behave on the input [1,1,2,3]?

Comment: it never happens. Because the elements in the list are all unique.

Answer (score 37):

Using a list comprehension is the easiest way.

```
import Data.List

pairs :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
pairs l = [(x,y) | (x:ys) <- tails l, y <- ys]
```

This only generates the relevant pairs so you don't have to filter out any duplicates as a separate step. `tails [1,2,3,4]` generates the lists of tails `[[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4], [3,4], [4], []]` and the list comprehension picks the first element from each tail and pairs it with the rest of the elements in that tail.

Comment: This should be the answer. The other answers require the list's elements to be have an `Ord` or `Eq` instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `nub` function:

```
import Data.List
uniq_pairs l = nub [(x,y) | x <-l, y<-l, x < y]
```

Output:

```
*Main> uniq_pairs  [1,2,3,4]
[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)]
```

Comment: Many thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: @NegarAlinaghi if elements of `l` are unique, using `nub` here is useless.

Comment: @lisyarus But, in general, if the list does have duplicate elements, `nub` will be needed to get unique pairs.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your example, this seems to be what you want

```
unique_pairs l = [(x,y) | x <- l, y <- l, x < y]
```

By the way, these are not just *unique pairs*, but *unique pairs up to transposition*.